# Dynamic chart updates only when I let go of the scroll bar

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have done the usual scroll-bar to update the chart using dynamic name range. Now the problem is the chart only updates when I release the scroll bar. It does not update if I keep it pressed.

I can see that the data is updating if I keep the scroll bar pressed (I just display the value in the chart data's range), but the chart itself only updates when I let go of the scroll bar.

Is there a way to force the chart to update? Or possibly to use some other control, apart from scroll-bar. Or even fake the release of scroll bar?

Excel 2010, Win 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the scroll bar from among the Forms controls? It's the more robust. However, the scroll bar from the ActiveX controls is a bit fancier, and the chart updates while you drag the little handle without waiting for you to release it.

ActiveX controls don't work on the Mac, and they tend to make your workbook unstable.